# KERNEL PANIC recurring after reinstall for Macbook Pro OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, firefox, kernel-panic

We reinstalled operating system at apple genius bar due to 3-4 previous crashes. Updated and timemachine restored files but it has started crashing again. Is it a firefox problem? Has the problem been reinstalled by timemachine backup? please advise, best twelvemouths

```
ERROR REPORT:

Interval Since Last Panic Report:  146898 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          3
Anonymous UUID:                    3B32906B-6924-46B7-BD6B-B86DFE1A2A26

Wed Jul 29 22:32:19 2015
panic(cpu 0 caller 0x2abf6a): Kernel trap at 0x356f3ad9, type 14=page fault, 
registers:
CR0: 0x80010033, CR2: 0x00000030, CR3: 0x00101000, CR4: 0x00000660
EAX: 0x23d58000, EBX: 0x00000027, ECX: 0x23d5912c, EDX: 0x00000000
CR2: 0x00000030, EBP: 0x35092b88, ESI: 0x00000000, EDI: 0x07bcf800
EFL: 0x00010206, EIP: 0x356f3ad9, CS:  0x00000004, DS:  0x3509000c
Error code: 0x00000000

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address (4 potential args on stack)

No mapping exists for frame pointer
Backtrace terminated-invalid frame pointer 0xbfff5918
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace (with dependencies):
         com.apple.ATIRadeonX1000(6.3.6)@0x356c0000->0x3571bfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.2.1)@0x35143000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.2.1)@0x351e6000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.6.5)@0x2e99a000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: firefox

Mac OS version:
10K549

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386
System model name: MacBookPro1,1 (Mac-F425BEC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 21686133350263
unloaded kexts:
(none)
loaded kexts:

Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD7500BPVT-00HXZT1, 698.64 GB
Parallel ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-857
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8501, 0xfd400000 / 6
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub, 0x05e3  (Genesys Logic, Inc.), 0x0606, 0xfd300000 / 2
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x1006, 0xfd330000 / 3
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x0250, 0xfd332000 / 5
USB Device: iP4500 series, 0x04a9  (Canon Inc.), 0x10c4, 0xfd310000 / 4
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x0218, 0x1d200000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8240, 0x5d200000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8205, 0x7d100000 / 2
FireWire Device: Hard Drive FW/USB, LaCie, Up to 400 Mb/sec

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

First try 'verify disk permissions' using Disk utility and verify/repair disk. Also, have you tried with Apple Hardware Test?

The instructions for Hardware Test are detailed here:

[Using Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257)